# How to add a custom role to service account using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I created a service account: `name@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and a custom role `mycustomrole`.

How with `gcloud` command can I add the custom role to this service account?

When I try

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
  --member="serviceAccount:myserviceaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role=projects/myproject/roles/mycustomrole \
  --verbosity=debug
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The role name must be in the form "roles/{role}", "organizations/{organization_id}/roles/{role}", or "projects/{project_id}/roles/{role}".
```

I tried already:

```
  --role=roles/mycustomrole
  --role=projects/myproject/roles/mycustomrole
  --role=projects/myproject/roles/customrole/mycustomrole
```

Comment: I was able to repro your error **if** I used an incorrect role name. Please try `gcloud iam roles list --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(name)"` and confirm that there is indeed a project-level custom role called `mycustomrole`. The name is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes. Thats helped. It turns out that all custom roles are named projects/<projectID>/roles/CustomRole and the next CustomRole would get some numbers added. I was using a wrong format of projects/<projectID>/roles/CustomRole/Name_of_the_role. Thank you.

Comment: @tr53, Seems like your issue has been resolved. Can you please post the resolution steps you had done as an answer for the greater visibility of the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin I was able to solve this.

When creating a role in GCP, by default their ID is in format of CustomRoleXXXX, where XXXX is a random number.

I was trying to use the name of the custom role instead of its ID.

All commands:

Create a custom role via UI.

Check its ID in the UI or by running:

```
gcloud iam roles list --project=<PROJECT ID> --format="value(name)"
```

Attach a custom role to service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT ID> \
  --member="serviceAccount:myserviceaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role=<CUSTOM ROLE ID> \
  --verbosity=debug
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the following command and it worked in my case :

```bash
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
  --member="serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role=projects/my-project/roles/my.role.name \
  --verbosity=debug
```

I was able to add the custom role `projects/my-project/roles/my.role.name` to the SA `serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

For the custom role, you have to put the role ID, this ID is displayed in the role detail page :

[image]

If you tip the correct params and if it still results in an error, can you update your `gcloud` version and try again please ?

```bash
gcloud components update
```